# Let $f$ be a family of sets. Prove that there is a unique set $A$ such that $f \subseteq \mathscr P (A)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $f$ is a family of sets. Prove that there is a unique set $A$ such that

$$f \subseteq \mathscr P (A)$$.

**Proof:**

Let $A= \cup f$. Let $X \in f$, and now let $y \in X$. Clearly, $y \in \cup f$, so $f \subseteq \mathscr P (A)$.

For uniqueness, suppose $f \subseteq \mathscr P (C)$ and $f \subseteq \mathscr P (D)$.

---

At this point, I have trouble showing $C=D$ for the uniqueness part because it's a biconditional . I could for instance let $x \in C$, but how would that be useful if I don't have any useful givens it seems. In short,  How would you prove uniqueness here?

Comment: There is no _unique_ $A$ with this property -- if $f\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$ then $f\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$ for every superset $B$ of $A$ too. But there is a unique _smallest_ $A$ with this property.

Comment: And even then, we could have $A$ infinite, in which case "smallest" needs qualification.

Comment: @M10687 Smallest with regard to inclusion does not need qualification even in the infinite case: For any other $B$ such that $f \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, it is true that $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: @McFry I was thinking of smallest in terms of cardinality for some reason, which isn't relevant here. My mistake.